# A good database modeling tool?

Tags: database-design

Could you guys recommend me a good db modeling tool? Mainly for SQL Server...

thanks!

Comment: Try this tool for SQL Server Physical models.

Info can be found here...

https://www.facebook.com/DataModelerTool/

or here...

https://plus.google.com/108968161662966473138

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is for SQL Server I like the DB Diagram from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: It works very well, but I find the GUI very, very clumsy.

Comment: Have you tried [SqlDBM](http://sqldbm.com/) ? 
It is one of the best tools I have found so far after researching many (like Erwin, Vertabelo etc) , SqlDMB has tons of handy features. It is online tool, absolutely free with very friendly UI.

Answer (score 8):

If your employer is paying, [ER Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/erstudio/) is fantastic.  I don't know how other people can function without it.  It easily makes me 50% more productive.

Answer (score 4):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/index.php) has a module that allows for the creation of Entity Relationship Diagrams. However, I've never used it for this purpose, so I don't know how good it is, but I do like StarUML for UML diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

Funny as it is I've found:

[WWW SQL Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/)

to be useful in a pinch.  I'm also a fan of his [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.wangz.net/cgi-bin/pp/gsqlparser/sqlpp/sqlformat.tpl) though by "instant" he means "not T-SQL" so you have to some slight hand editing of Profiler recorded statements to use his system fully.

Answer (score 3):

I heartily recommend [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html).

Alternatively Visio for Enterprise Architects works moderately well and you could get it together with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

ERwin Data Modeler is the best tool for Enterprise database modelling in my opinion.
I've used it a number of times and it is great.
See: http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=260

It is a little bit pricey, but it is worth it. You can also trial it for free.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Navicat Data Modeler. It's the best data modeling tool I've found so far. It has a free version.

Free version can be found at: [Navicat Data Modeler](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_datamodeler/modeler_overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for drawing Entity Relationship Diagrams, then I suggest Visio.  It will even build your database from the Diagram.

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/ for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use SQL Server Management Studio also for quickly doing stuff, but when I am doing the actual implementation or more advanced stuff I use [EMS Sql Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/manager). It is quite a nice tool with far more advanced and more numerous features than Sql Management studio. You can think of it as MS SQL Management Studio on steroids. Takes a bit of getting used to the UI though, but still straight forward enough. And if you get their [package with all their peoducts](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/studio/mssql) you get a ton of great utilities as well.

If its just diagramming thoguh i will use Visio.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using for some time with great success what used to be called 'Case Studio'.  It's now called '[Toad Data Modeller](http://www.casestudio.com/)'..

It's pay, but quite good, worth at least a trial.

Comment: Case Studio is good, now it's not really good anymore after it became TDM...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always liked [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia), it's ubiquitous, portable, easy to use and supports a whole bunch of other diagrams other than just ER/UML so I can use it to make diagrams for non-techies.

Comment: Dia is great, but a diagramming tool is only but one small part of a database modelling tool.

Answer (score 1):

ModelRight, from http://www.modelright.com is very good for physical modeling. Excellent support for Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used pencil and paper quite successfully to get the initial entities and relationships down. Especially good if designing with other people, you don't get distracted by the GUI interface, mousing around, getting the background gradients right, etc. Then you can translate it into Visio or Dia or a UML tool that generates both the SQL Schema and your object model...

Usually after this time constraints mean you end up in TOAD or your DB tool of choice getting the tables, indexes, foreign keys and stuff implemented in straight SQL or with their table designer tool. Changes will inevitably come up downstream so don't spend too long getting things exactly, just get the structure right.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw ERDs using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) records.  That will not trak/organize your metadata, geneate your DDL or anything else for that matter - but it will give you an entity relationship diagram that you can easily edit/update.

It will handle all the layout/arrangement details of the diagram for you.  It does a pretty good job of this.  It is sort of a declarative diagram-drawing language.  Very simple to learn.  Requires nothing but a text editor to use.  Many applications use its abilities behind the scenes to generate their diagrams also.

Answer (score 0):

I second Embarcadero ERStudio. Not cheap but powerful, multiplatform and really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using SQL Server, as I've mentioned in other posts Visio probably will work really well for you. You probably already have it or your IT shop does so the cost is negligible and it can import an existing database or if you build from scratch can export it to a designated SQL Server.

I've used it several times and have been happy with the results.

Answer (score 0):

[ModelRight](http://www.modelright.com/) is the best tool out there - especially for the money.