# Tools to visualize a database and understand the datamodel quickly

Tags: database, data-modeling, visualization, erd

I have several SQL Server 2005 databases ranging from 20 – 600 tables in an application and no documentation. I am looking for a database diagramming tool that is smart enough to pick tables that seem to be related to one entity (e.g., tables related to Patient, tables related to Orders) or one functionality (e.g., Patient Management, Order Management) and show them separately instead of drawing the entire database.

In the past, I have seen tables related to one piece of functionality represented in one color in the ER diagrams. In a well designed database, perhaps there will be multiple schemas that group tables related to one functionality  together. But as all these tables are in one schema, and I want a tool that is smart enough to perhaps suggest which tables should go together under one schema. It won’t be perfect but perhaps it is intelligent enough to examine which tables should go together (for example based on relationships between them or based on which tables seem to be accessed together in the stored procs).

The bottom line is that I want to understand the data-model as quickly as possible. A tool called Schema Spy ( http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ )  seem to be headed in the right direction, but I was wondering if anyone knew better/more comprehensive tools.

Thanks.

Comment: Another tool that allows for visualization is is http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/schemaball/ and seems to be helpful too.

Comment: That Schemaball app looks very impressive. Too bad I have to setup a Perl environment just to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Visio at all? While it does not satisfy everything you asked for it can reverse engineer a database and make very appealing diagrams with a little work.

I have never used it to understand an existing database, but I have used it to explain databases I have created.

Comment: The Reverse Engineer Wizard isn't available in Visio Professional 2016-2019 or Visio Standard 2016-2019. In order to use the database modeling features, one should consider upgrade to Visio Online Plan 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [wsSqlSrvDoc](http://www.wolfsys.net/index.php/software/windows-desktop/84-wssqlsrvdoc). It's a nice little tool that works with Sql Server extended properties and creates a MS Word document.

The print-out of all column properties (with foreign key relations) works out of the box. For further descriptions on each field you have to set up extended properties of those columns in Sql Server Management Studio.

The downside however is that it's not free (but quite afordable). And if you just need to create a documentation for a "not work in progress" DB that's more or less finished than it would be enough to use the free trial i'll guess.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to an older question, Link:[A good database modeling tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166557/a-good-database-modeling-tool)

From the answer to this question, e.g. [fabFORCE.net dbDesigner](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) might be what you are looking for.